# Looping through Properties.Settings using a string

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, properties.settings

Is there a way to loop through Settings using an identifier like the following

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.["S" + i.ToString()]= 0;//identifier expected
}
```

To substitute these:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.S1 = 0;
Properties.Settings.Default.S2 = 0;
Properties.Settings.Default.S3 = 0;
Properties.Settings.Default.S4 = 0;
Properties.Settings.Default.S5 = 0;
```

Problem is that it's throwing an **identifier expected** error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like so, i.e. remove the dot '.' after `Default` to invoke the indexing operator

```
Properties.Settings.Default["S" + i.ToString()]= 0
```

Comment: :D np - I am sure you are not the only one who sometimes get stuck with simple errors (me included!)